# Entity Framework: exclusive record update - force to increment current value instead of replacing it

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to create some kind of financial system and I would like to update account balance in high concurrency mode. Of course I need exclusive access to particular account record to read actual value and update it. Unfortunately I can't serialize reading of existing record using EF. 
Question: is it possible to force EF to generate updates like:

```
update MyTable
set Balance=Balance+xxx  //where xxx my balance increment
where ID=yyy
```

instead of

```
update MyTable
set Balance=NewValue
where ID=...
```

Or have I missed some other correct approach ? Currently I see only one possible solution: update balance via separate connection using direct SQL commands without interaction with Entity Framework.

**How to reproduce:**
I'm creating ASP.NET application and each thread has it's own DbContext to connect to the database. The very simplified form of my models are following:

```
public class Account{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public decimal Balance {get; set;}
}
public class Entry {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int AccountId {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
}
```

Just after the posting an Entry I need to update account balance. I'm using JMeter to emulate multiuser site access. The simplest test is to post the same amount in the several dozens of threads and calculate total balance for all accounts after that. For example, if we have 20 threads, 10 requrests for each thread and post amount=50 for each, we should get 10000 as a total balance. 
I know that I need to carefully handle database locks here and I know how to do this on the low level of DB access. I just wanted to find a way to use Entity Framework without any external stuff. I've already played with `TransactionScope` a lot but it looks like I can;t serialize read access of the current balance value.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Entity Framework is the wrong tool for the job.  It is not meant to completely replace every interaction you have with your database.  To do what you are saying, your best bet is to run the SQL directly.

However, I would suggest a change to your database structure.  You stated that you are going to have 200 (20 thread * 10 requests) updates.  Why not make an activity table.  Those 200 updates will be translated to 200 inserts into the activity table.  Instead of setting `Amount = Amount + 50`, just insert `50` into the activity table.  This way there is no chance of any thread stepping on the other.  Additionally, you get a history of the transactions, and if you need to back one out, it is nice and easy.

**Edit**

I just re-read the question.  It looks like your `Entry` table is what I am suggesting.  In that case, database normalization says that you should remove `Balance` from Account.  Calculate it on the fly when you need to display it.